# How to design texture for image in Android xml

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am new to Android. I want to keep texture for my Android background screen. How can I create a texture in Android design?

I am designing using android-xml.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that your texture image is named: `texture1.png`.

1. Put `texture1.png` in `/res/drawable` folder.
2. Create `texture.xml` in `/res/drawable` and put this code on it:

   ```
   <bitmap
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:src="@drawable/texture1"
   android:tileMode="repeat" />
   ```
3. Add this line to your layout xml's root (usually the root is a `<LinearLayout>`):

   ```
   android:background="@drawable/texture"
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to create through style

Comment: You can add `android:background="@drawable/texture"` to your style.

Comment: No what i was trying to askis that we can specify the gradient, radius etc as attributes Same is it possible to define a texture, because i am using another image as background

Comment: If you are using a background image then WHY you want to add a texture background?? Only one will be visible.